# How to set clutter flow permanent for pictures folder on maverick

Tags: 10.10, nautilus-elementary

I would like to make the clutter flow on the Maverick permanent for the ~/pictures folder.
when I close nautilus clutter flow resets and I have to again press F4 and resize the area. Which defeats the purpose of an eyecandy app IMO.
Is there a way to set to permanent for the pictures folder.

thanks
Gaurav Butola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible right now, but it is a planned feature.

Comment: I wish it gets implemented soon.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible becuase i've done it.. You can have it default all the time or just for individual folders or just create new launchers to locations you want it.

Yes it's maybe not perfect but it does the job.. It's a simple setup which can be easily undone just by changing whatever launcher command you change back to nautilus for example..

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1721799

If somebody can help with setting the default clutterview size then please do as that's what I wanted to do with this.. I've been tinkering with the window resize options of xdotool and now i'm toying with the gtk files but only minor success so far.. If somebody can make it happen with xdotool then it will be perfect becuase the resize code can just be added to the sh script which opens clutterview.